# How to work with client_storage without the "NotImplementedError" in flet, Python (Flutter for python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flet

Well, I want to write an async app on Flet with Telethon. It;s my first time so do not judge strictly pls.

That's my code

main.py

```
import flet as ft
import main_page


async def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Telegram resender 3000"
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.START
    await page.update_async()

    await page.add_async(main_page.MainPage(page))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)
```

main_page.py

```
import flet as ft
import telethon
from .load_env import *
import asyncio
import os

import support_classes as sc


class MainPage(ft.UserControl):

    def __init__(self, page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page

    def build(self):
        self.idx = 0
        # create text
        self.add_account_text = ft.Text(value="Add your tg account here")

        # create input for writing phone number and ADD btn
        self.add_phone_number = ft.TextField(
            hint_text="Enter your phone number")
        self.add_phone_btn = ft.FloatingActionButton(
            icon=ft.icons.ADD, on_click=self.register_new_acc)

        self.accs_list = ft.Row(controls=[])  # create field for tg accs
        self.upload_tg_accs_btn = ft.IconButton(
            icon=ft.icons.DOWNLOAD,
            icon_color="blue400",
            icon_size=30,
            tooltip="Upload existing telegram accounts",
            on_click=self.get_tg_accs,
        )

        self.add_account_part = ft.Column(
            width=300,
            controls=[
                ft.Row(
                    controls=[
                        self.add_account_text,
                        self.add_phone_number,
                        self.add_phone_btn
                    ]
                ),
                ft.Row(controls=[
                    self.accs_list,
                    self.upload_tg_accs_btn,
                ]),
            ])

        return self.add_account_part

    async def register_new_acc(self, e):

        # add field for code
        self.code_recieve_input = ft.TextField(
            hint_text="Enter the code and wait...")

        self.add_account_part.controls.append(self.code_recieve_input)
        await self.add_account_part.update_async()

        # create a session and get request for a code
        client = telethon.TelegramClient(
            str(self.idx), api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

        # save the phone
        phone = self.add_phone_number.value

        # make input empty
        self.add_phone_number.value = ""

        await client.start(phone=phone, code_callback=lambda: self.code_receive(phone))

    async def code_receive(self, phone):
        # wait for user's answer
        await asyncio.sleep(30)

        # remove code input
        self.add_account_part.controls.remove(self.code_recieve_input)
        await self.add_account_part.update_async()

        # add a new acc to a list
        acc = sc.TGAcc(
            num=self.code_recieve_input.value,
            idx=self.idx,
            del_func=self.delete_acc
        )

        self.accs_list.controls.append(acc)
        await self.accs_list.update_async()

        # add number to a storage
        tg_accs = {}
        # if we already have nums
        if self.page.client_storage.contains_key_async("tg_accs"):
            tg_accs = self.page.client_storage.get("tg_accs")

        self.page.client_storage.set("tg_accs", tg_accs + {self.idx: phone})

        self.idx += 1  # increase the idx (of accounts)
        return self.code_recieve_input.value

    async def delete_acc(self, acc):
        # delete from list and update
        self.accs_list.controls.remove(acc)
        await self.accs_list.update_async()

        # remove session file
        os.remove(f'{acc.idx}.session')

    async def get_tg_accs(self, e):

        # create list of all connected accs
        if self.page.client_storage.contains_key('tg_accs'):
            accs_list = [sc.TGAcc(num=v, idx=k, del_func=self.delete_acc)
                         for k, v in self.page.client_storage.get("tg_accs").items()]

        # set our data
        self.accs_list.controls = accs_list

        await self.accs_list.update_async()
```

tg_acc.py

```
import flet as ft
import os

class TGAcc(ft.UserControl):
    
    def __init__(self, num, idx, del_func):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = num
        self.idx = idx
        self.del_func = del_func
        
    def build(self):
        # build the container
        self.container = ft.Column(
            controls=[
                ft.Row(
                    controls=[
                        ft.Text(f"{self.idx} = {self.num}"),
                        ft.IconButton(
                            icon=ft.icons.DELETE_FOREVER_ROUNDED,
                            icon_color="pink600",
                            icon_size=30,
                            tooltip="Delete account",
                            on_click=self.delete_acc
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
        
        return self.container
    
    async def delete_acc(self, e):
        await self.del_func(self)
```

Also I have load_env.py file there I load all secret data.

And I "sorted" these file into folders so that's the screen. I also added screen of UI.
[image: floders and files]

[image: UI]

**So, problem: **
I need to load data from client_storage in startup of a program and after write it into self.accs_list.controls. idk how do it on startup of all, so I created a download btn, by clicking on it data should load but all that loads is an exception `raise NotImplementedError()`.

I tried to delete `self.page = page` in **init** of MainPage and just use self.page everywhere in code below but no result has appeared(

Here an error, that's always the same

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-15' coro=<__connect_internal_async.<locals>.on_event() done, defined at /home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_runtime/app.py:425> exception=NotImplementedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_runtime/app.py", line 427, in on_event
    await conn.sessions[e.sessionID].on_event_async(
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/page.py", line 482, in on_event_async
    await handler(ce)
  File "/home/felix/Documents/code/flet-telegram-repost/main_page/main_page.py", line 115, in get_tg_accs
    if self.page.client_storage.contains_key('tg_accs'):
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/client_storage.py", line 46, in contains_key
    self.__page.invoke_method(
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/page.py", line 859, in invoke_method
    result = self._send_command(
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/page.py", line 700, in _send_command
    return self.__conn.send_command(
  File "/home/felix/anaconda3/envs/telegram_bot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/connection.py", line 21, in send_command
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

idk how to fix my problem, in docs any examples with the client_storage + ft.UserControl I didnt find. That's my first time so I can do veeeery stupid mistakes.

If anyone knows how to load data from client_storage on startup of Flet app write pls, I listen carefully)

Comment: FYI, You should not use screenshots for information that is pure text (like the exception traceback). You should copy/paste the text. Screenshots are hard to read and people can't simply copy relevant strings.

Comment: Srry... I edited info. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Debugging: While it may seem overwhelming you could follow the traceback through flet within your site-packages directory or on GitHub. I did not see where to fix it but, apparently, your `page` used a connection's (synchronous) `send_command`. For `Connection` itself and possibly the sub-class you effectively use that method is not implemented - hence the error. You could add debug output to your local files.
As a wild shot, maybe you need to use `client_storage.contains_key_async` instead.

Answer (score 0):

asyncio just makes client_storage crash with error that you can't fix yourself. They better fix this quick, now the only option is to get rid of asyncio or not use client_storage at all.

## Comparing sync vs. async

My **sync**hronous version

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'test'
    page.client_storage.set('test', 'test')
    page.add(ft.Test(value='test'))

ft.app(main)
```

runs as expected. But my **async**hronous version

```
import flet as ft

async def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'test'
    page.client_storage.set('test', 'test')
    await page.add(ft.Test(value='test'))

ft.app(main)
```

runs into a `NotImplementedError` too

```
    page.client_storage.set('test', 'test')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/client_storage.py", line 13, in set
    self.__page.invoke_method(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/page.py", line 853, in invoke_method
    result = self._send_command(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/page.py", line 696, in _send_command
    return self.__conn.send_command(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flet_core/connection.py", line 21, in send_command
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Please explain what convinced you that asyncio and client_storage will not work together.

Comment: I've checked it myself, with trial and error investigating possible solutions. Screenshots: https://telegra.ph/title-10-03-78 (sorry for the resolution, it's the best I could find)

Comment: Okay. When you provide an answer on stackoverflow you should help others get to the same conclusion you did. In this case, you should have put the content of the screenshot into your answer. (I edited your answer but the edit has to wait for approval.) That way somebody else could copy your code, investigate how it fails and possibly provide a fix or workaround.  
Incidentally, have you tried using the storage's async method, i.e. `page.client_storage.set_async`?

Comment: Slightly paranoid side note: I recommend for anything you post here (even in a screenshot) to hide personally identifiable data, e.g. your username and machine name.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

As described and demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77717460/17865804), when running a `flet` app as an [`async` app](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/async-apps/), you need to use the `async` versions of the various methods provided by `flet`, by adding `_async` at the end of the method. Hence, as shown in your example, the `NotImplementedError` is raised due to calling the *sync* version of the `contains_key()` method of `client_storage` :

```py
async def get_tg_accs(self, e):
    if self.page.client_storage.contains_key('tg_accs'):
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        # ...
```

### Solution

Instead, you should use its `async` counterpart by adding `_async` at the end of it, i.e., `contains_key_async()` instead of `contains_key()`, and `await` that method, as shown below:

```py
async def get_tg_accs(self, e):
    if await self.page.client_storage.contains_key_async('tg_accs'):
        pass
```