# How do I return a FileResponse (or StreamingResponse) in flet-fastapi?

Tags: python, flutter, file, fastapi, flet

I'm actually trying to create a web-app that would ask a person some info, than edit `\*.docx` with jinja and return this `\*.docx` to the person as a download.

I'm having trouble making `flet-fastapi` return a `FileResponse`.
My workdir looks like this:

```
__pycache__/
.venv/
output/
    output/test.docx
main.py
requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt:

```
flet-fastapi
flet
uvicorn
pydantic
fastapi
```

main.py:

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import flet as ft
import flet_fastapi
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app=FastAPI):
    await flet_fastapi.app_manager.start()
    yield
    await flet_fastapi.app_manager.shutdown()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

# I believe that it doesn't matter which endpoint we choose here, since later we mount
# our flet on the root-path. Decorator is here because without it "return FileResponse()"
# does nothing at all.
@app.get("/")
async def dl_test(page: ft.Page):
    async def download(e):
        return FileResponse(f"output/test.docx", media_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", filename="test.docx")
    await page.add_async(ft.OutlinedButton(text="Get file", on_click=download))
    await page.update_async()

app.mount("/", flet_fastapi.app(dl_test))
```

This code is the minimal reproducible code.
To reproduce it, we can prepare our virtual environment:

```
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then run it:

```
uvicorn --reload main:app
```

As we run it, we can see an exception:

> fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'flet_core.page.Page'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None.

How can we make "return FileResponse()" working?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) answer your question? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804) as well.

Comment: @Chris Very thank you for advice, checked these. I've tried StreamingResponse, yielding, specifying headers for response, but all these solutions are crushing when we try to use them with Flet. When we apply our flet-fastapi route decorator func to our Flet page-rendering func, it won't start, instead telling us (through pydantic) that our response model class 'flet_core.page.Page' is invalid. I don't know, why, but redirect_response=None won't work too. I believe that Flet somehow overrides our implicit returning type. Maybe we can have API framework that manages FastAPI and Flet underneath?

Comment: Sorry, typo: meant "model_response=None" instead of "redirect_response=None"

Comment: @Chris Thank you, added a minimal reproducible codes block. There are three examples of non-working popular solutions of my problem. Now you can copy-paste one of them and try. I didn't specify any version of libs because in my main project I use latest.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for confusing examples, I'm new to the StackOverflow. Here I tried to rework the question to make it simplier to understand what is my trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to use [`launch_url(url)`](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/page/#launch_urlurl). Since you run your `flet` app as an [`async` app](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/async-apps/) (such as when [running `flet` with `fastapi`](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/deploying-web-app/running-flet-with-fastapi)), you need to use the `async` version of that method, i.e., `launch_url_async(url)` (though it might not be that clear in `flet`'s documentation), by adding `_async` at the end of that method, as well as `await`ing it (see the example below).

You also need to make sure that the FastAPI endpoint—that is responsible for downloading the file—returns a `FileResponse` or `StreamingResponse` (depending on your needs—please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) for more details and examples) with the `Content-Disposition` header appropriately set, in order to force downloading the file (specially, when it is in a format that usually opens in the browser, i.e., `txt`, `pdf`, `mp4`, etc.) instead of displaying its contents in the browser/app (please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804) for more info on that).

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import flet as ft
import flet_fastapi


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await flet_fastapi.app_manager.start()
    yield
    await flet_fastapi.app_manager.shutdown()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/download')
async def download():
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="test.txt"'}
    return FileResponse("test.txt", headers=headers)


async def main(page: ft.Page):
    async def download_file(e):
        await page.launch_url_async(url='/download', web_window_name='_self')
        
    await page.add_async(ft.FilledButton(text="Download File", on_click=download_file))
    await page.update_async()


# mount flet app to the root path
app.mount('/', flet_fastapi.app(main))
```

Comment: would you have an idea how to capture the json data if the return is not a fileresponse? but a `return {"msg": "student home"}` basically i would like to capture the value `student home`